# java.lang.NullPointerException In Jaspersoft when creating a barcode with variable

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a bar code and placed it inside a variable even sent him(variable) from Java , but when I click on the barcode in properties, this exception occurs

[image: Error]
[image: jrxml definition]

Can anyone tell me what is the solution to this problem !?

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: You send parameters not variables from java, however the error is when you try to edit it in JasperSoft Studio?, not when generating the report, preview, correct?... Please post the error log so we have more details.

Comment: there is a problem in java code, it does not display a barCode in report .

Comment: Error that appears :

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at org.xml.sax.helpers.NewInstance.newInstance(NewInstance.java:82)
at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:228

Comment: at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:221)
 at org.apache.batik.dom.util.SAXDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.batik.dom.util.SAXDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)

Comment: at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createSVGDocument(Unknown Source)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.ensureSvg(BatikRenderer.java:209)
 at )

Comment: at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1584)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:999)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportFrame(JRPdfExporter.java:2807)

Comment: Next time post your stacktrace in question (edit question). My guess is that you are missing a library or having problem with xerces jars (multiple, incorrect jars). You should check that you have all jar in the jasper report distribution and which other jars you have that contains xml implementation